# Axios POST request as a promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, axios, es6-promise

I am writing an async function made up of quite a few different different methods and the order of execution is important. I want to make an axios post request early on in the function therefore I am trying to turn the method I used in to a promise to be sure that it executes sequentially in the main function. I am including both the way I did it initially which was working and the method I made to abstract some of the code which is not working I believe due to the fact that it is an arrow function with an await command inside of it. My question is one: will my initial method of calling the post request execute sequentially and if not how can I fix this abstracted method so that it will work?

working attempt (code inside of main function):

```
var form = new FormData();
      form.append("arguments", JSON.stringify({"ID":`${zohoLeadID}`, "folderNumber": `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/${rootFolder}`}));
      const axiosRes = await axios.post(
        'https://myreturnaddress.net', 
        form, 
        { headers: form.getHeaders() }
 );
```

failed attempt at promise:

```
async function postData(zohoLeadID, root) {
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append("arguments", JSON.stringify({"ID":`${zohoLeadID}`, "folderNumber": `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/${root}`}));
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const axiosRes = await axios.post('myhttpsaddress.net', form, {headers: form.getHeaders()})
            resolve(axiosRes);
        } catch(err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Your "failed attempt at promise" is an antipattern - you shouldn't create a promise your self when you already have a promise that is returned by `axios.post(...)`. Also note that you are already using promises with `async-await`.

Comment: _"will my initial method of calling the post request execute sequentially"_ - not sure what you are trying to ask. You only have a single post request, so why are you worried about the sequence?

Comment: In your first code block, what is the problem?  You're awaiting the natural promise that `axios.post()` already returns so you already have the value you need and `await` already pauses execution of this function to allow you to sequence things.

Comment: @Yousaf so it will execute in order if I just use the await axios.post(...)?

Comment: `await` will pause the execution of this particular function (the one that contains the `await`).  It will not pause execution outside the function.  This will allow you to properly sequence things within the function.  This is the entire point of `await`.

Comment: @jim if you are asking whether the statements _after_ the `await axios.post(....)` will execute in sequence, then yes, they will execute in sequence unless there's some traditional callback-based asynchronous code after the `await axios.post(...)`. If you have more asynchronous code that returns a promise, just use `await` and they will execute one after the other.

Comment: @Yousaf and jfriend00 thank you for the answers very helpful.